# Saving a reference to jquery element in a hash array

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, namespaces

For performance, I'll often save references to dom elements in a var, such as:

```
var $header = $("#header");
```

If I have multiple elements, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
var someNamespace = {
  $header : $("#header"),
  $footer : $("#footer")
}
```

The latter seems to throw an error. How do you handle this without creating a ton of vars?

Comment: Why would you need tons of vars? ;)

Comment: _"Seems to throw an error"_? What error? What does the JS console say? I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted, indeed it worked fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/tSzMH/ (By the way, the JavaScript term is "object", not "hash array".)

Comment: @nnnnnn. except it was `var someNamespace = {
    $header = $("#header"),
    $footer = $("#footer")
};​` couple of minutes ago. **:(**

Comment: Stupid late-night mistake. I was reassigning the namespace obj later instead of appending to it. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
var someNamespace = {
    $header = $("#header"),
    $footer = $("#footer")
};​
```

**replace `=` with `:`**

```
var someNamespace = {
    $header: $("#header"),
    $footer: $("#footer")
};​
```

This is the syntax for `object literals` declarations.

Read more in [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: This was a careless error in my retyping the code, thanks for catching it. There is a problem beyond this.

Comment: @b-b. What is the error? what are you trying to do? How does the code using `someNamespace` look like?